# Grail 2.4.3 AddTo memory leak issue

Tags: database, grails

I've read a lot of data from a CSV file that I now need to store in the database, I'm doing so like this with a cascading save:

```
class saveData() {

def data = session.getAttribute("Data")

def dataInfo = new DataInfo(firstName: params.firstName, lastName: params.lastName, email: params.email)

    data.collect{
        .addToCustomerDetails(new dataCustomerInfo(number: it[0], email: it[1], email: it[2]))
        .save(flush:true)
    }

   if (dataInfo.validate()) {
        redirect(action: "list", id: dataInfo.id)
    }
}
```

The data set could be a million lines, the first thousand or so are fine but then things start to slow down and eventually I give up. A user might have a grace timeout login of 15 minutes but this process seems to take 30 mins to do 25,000 lines?

Is the process AddTo the most efficient when using such a large about of data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that you should use a bi-dir one-to-many here. It's not expected to hold millions of references. 
So 1st, use uni-dir o2m with `belongsTo`, it has no limitations.

Second, you are facing a classic hibernate gotcha with `batch updates`, which in conjunction with bi-dir o2m leads to session overflow. You should flush the session each 1k lines or so:

```
int count = 0
data.each{
  new dataCustomerInfo(number: it[0], email: it[1], email: it[2], dataInfo:dataInfo )
      .save( flush:0 == count % 1000 )
}
```

P.S. Do your domain classes names really start in lower-case?

Comment: thanks again, I can't seem to get the cascade to save correctly...  I get the data in the database however it's not creating the index to the correct DataInfo, it's just inserting the data.